# How to ping using C sockets

Tags: c, windows, sockets, ping, icmp

- Compiler: Code::Blocks(GNU GCC)
- Platform: Windows(x86)
- Includes: winsock.h winsock2.h (ws2_32 is linked as well)

I am currently trying to write a program that will read a text file containing a list of IP-Addresses and ping each IP-Addresses respectively. If the host responds to the ping then the host's IP-Address will be copied to a seconded file specified by the user. Unfourtantly this is the first time I have used C's socket library and I cannot find a good tutorial about how to ping using C. From what I understand of the couple tutorials I did find. I need to included a ICMP header, which is a struct containg the ICMP type, code, and checksum, in a IP datagram. But I have no idea how to go about doing so, should I declare the struct myself or is it declared in a header file? I am assuming that it is in a header but the tutorials contradicted each other about exactly where it is declared. I tired including icmp.h and netinet/icmp.h but my compiler complained that they don't exist so I created my own struct.

```
    struct echo_request
    {
        char type; // Type
        char code; // Code
        short checksum; // Checksum
        short id; // Identification
        short seq; // Sequence
        int time; // Time
        char data[16]; // Data
    };
```

I thought that I might be able to get away with it but I wasn't even able to compile my program because my compiler says that in_cksum()(checksum generator) is undefined.

To sum up my questions, what header files should I include, how do I create a ping packet, am I using the correct checksum generator function, should a ping be directed to port 80, and should the socket I use be RAW or DGRAM?

This is what I have so far, please note that I have purposely left out error checking.

```
    int socket_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);

    struct sockaddr_in address; //Initialize address struct
    memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address)); //Clear address struct

    //Declare address
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipaddress);
    address.sin_port = htons(80);

    //Bind socket to address
    bind(socket_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));

    //Create packet
    struct echo_request packet; //See above for declaration of struct
    memset(packet.data, 1, 16);
    packet.type = 8; //ECHO_REQUEST
    packet.code = 0;
    packet.time = gettime();
    packet.checksum = 0;
    packet.checksum = in_cksum(packet, sizeof(packet));
```

Comment: 1) the structure must be packed, make sure that compiler does not align fields 2) does Windows support raw sockets well (I don't know this)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have to implement the ping from scratch and you want only Windows solution, I'd second Anton's suggestion for IcmpSendEcho. If you have to implement ping, look at how [POCO](http://github.com/pocoproject/poco) ICMP package is implemented. It is portable code and it runs fine on Windows.

In regards to the specific questions, here are the answers:

> what header files should I include

```
#include <winsock2.h>
```

> how do I create a ping packet

See [ICMPv4PacketImpl::initPacket()](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.9.0/Net/src/ICMPv4PacketImpl.cpp#L125-L144) for an example of IPv4 packet.

> am I using the correct checksum generator function

Not for windows. See [ICMPPacketImpl::checksum()](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.9.0/Net/src/ICMPPacketImpl.cpp#L76-L100) for an example of checksum function.

> should a ping be directed to port 80

No. There's no such thing as port when it comes to ICMP. See [Does ICMP use a specific port?](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/39021)

> should the socket I use be RAW or DGRAM

It should be RAW.

Comment: @Alex does `ICMP` need running as `admin` and/or `root` to work?

Comment: @Top-Master usually, yes. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1189445/205386

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want a real solution, not just reimplementing PING for the sake of it.

I recommend using IP helper (ICMP.dll on pre-WinXP systems), specifically, [IcmpSendEcho](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or its enhanced versions, `IcmpSendEcho2`, `IcmpSendEcho2Ex`, for asynchronous operations).

There is a complete example of "pinging" a host on MSDN. It may be a good starting point.

Update: for GCC (mingw), link with -liphlpapi.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am aware of IcmpSendEcho but I want to implement a relatively portable solution.

Comment: but if your app does not have `admin-privileges` then `IcmpSendEcho` is the only choice according to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7691109/8740349